Optional backshifting in reported speech

I will do it tomorrow


a) He said he will do it tomorrow
b) He said he would do that tomorrow


I did it yesterday


a) He said he did it yesterday
b) He said he had done it yesterday


I have done it


a) He said he did it
b) He said he had done it

I know that in reported speech, if we believe that something is still true, we don't have to backshift. So, I could change nothing in example 1 while reporting it. Both 1A and 1B are fine. This is true about the future. But what about the past? I still believe someone did something in the past. So, do I have to backshift examples 2 and 3, or are they are able to stay the same, like example 1?

Backshifting or no backshifting doesn't depend on the tense of a sentence.. Reported speech of your first sentence can be - He said that he would do it the next day

@KateBunting It is changed

I understand that if he tells me something today for example " I did it yesterday" and when I report that and the day is still the same I could say "he said he had done it yesterday" and I don't change "yesterday", correct?

Yes, or "He said  he did it yesterday". 3a should be "He said [that] he has done it".

"He said he have done it" is not the right conjugation. I think you mean "he said he has done it," maybe a typo.
